# docker and "volatile volumes" ala /tmp

Tags: docker

I run a server with 2 Docker images, one does building and packaging and thus creates alot of shortlived stuff on /tmp.

I'd like this container /tmp to not be backed by persistent volume (union fs or volume) but to use the host's /tmp which in turn is a tmpfs volume and ideal for such operations. Saving access to a normal drive will have overhead and causes access to HDDs (wear-out), I would prefer to try to stay in RAM as much as possible.

Some options are:

- Bind /tmp/:/tmp to the docker process. Doesnt seem very secure, and problematic if another process accesses this directory
- Bind a volume to /tmp. This means its on the harddrive unless I manage to move it to /tmp.
  There is then still the issue of deleting this volume each time the container stops, since Id prefer a clean slate.
- Mount /tmp as tmpfs in the container. Seems the most sane option. Except that would mean editing all containers instead plainly using existing ones

I am new to Docker, maybe I am missing something obvious.

I search for a way to specify volumes which can or have to be dropped after the container stops. Or even are kept completely in RAM unless this is infeasible.
And additionally some easy way to mount /tmp as such a container.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Docker allows you to do this using the `--tmpfs` option.

For example;

```
docker run -it --tmpfs /tmp ubuntu
```

Or, using the "advanced" `--mount` syntax, which allows for additional options to be set:

```
docker run -it --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/tmp ubuntu
```

For more information, and additional options that can be used, see the ["Use tmpfs mounts" section](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/) in the documentation.

Comment: sounds exactly like what I wanted. But will read through the request and 1.10 docs before marking it as solved.
Thanks

Comment: Sure! If you want to give it a test now (not for production, just testing); nightly builds from master can be obtained via https://master.dockerproject.org

Comment: It's been 11 years since this answer: [docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/)

Comment: Updated my answer to include the documentation link now that it's available in current versions of docker

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a *tmpfs* partition on your container's `/tmp` location if you run that container with the `docker run` `--privileged` option:

```
docker run -it --privileged ubuntu bash -l
root@2ed296ef6a80:/# mount -t tmpfs -o size=256M tmpfs /tmp
root@2ed296ef6a80:/# mount
```

> ...
>
> tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=262144k)

---

Or you can create a *tmpfs* mount on the docker host and mount it as a volume in your container:

```
# TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
# mount -t tmpfs -o size=256M tmpfs $TMPDIR
# docker run -it -v $TMPDIR:/tmp ubuntu bash -l
root@0f0555ec96cb:/# mount | grep /tmp
```

> tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=262144k)

Comment: Except this wont work as easi when the image doesnt log in as root, but as user without even the possibiliy to change to root. The jenkins image is such example.

you`d have to trick around to mount the rw-portion in anout container or build (and maintain) your own image

Comment: I would highly discourage using `--privileged` for this; containers with `--privileged` are *not secure*, because all security options that containers provide are disabled, and because of that can take full `root` control of the host. Only use `--privileged` in exceptional situations.